# Minimizing a specific function over n variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Experimenting with something related to probability theory I came across the following $n$-variable function

$$ f(p_1,\ldots,p_n) = \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} \left ( (1-p_i)(1-p_{i-1})^i (1-p_{i+1})^{n-i} + p_i {n \choose i} \right ) $$

where $p_1,\ldots,p_n \in [0,1].$

The natural thing is to use the inequality $(1-p_i)^t \leq e^{-p_i t}$ but I don't know what to do from there.

Since I am very rusty with such optimizations I would like to ask if someone could find a good lower bound for this function ? What is a good approximation of the minimum of $f$ and how to obtain it?

If this is too hard, it would be nice to see if there is a set of values for $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ such that $f(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ is sub-exponential?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd start by taking derivatives with respect to the various $p_i$'s.

Comment: Try $p_i=0$ for all $i$ sub-exponential. Or do you mean $\sum_i p_i = 1$?

Comment: Try the transformation $x_i = 1- p_i$. Then you're really minimizing $\sum x_i x_{i-1}^i x_{i+1}^{n-i} - C(n,i) x_i$. Before I take a crack at it, can you verify whether or not $\sum_i p_i = 1$ is a constraint?

Comment: I'll also note a slight asymmetry in the formula that causes me to wonder: the first and last terms involve $C(n,2)$ and $C(n,n-1)$, which are unequal. Do you mean for the summation to begin at $i=1$ and to allow a $p_0$? That'd make things more symmetric.

Comment: @WillNelson The sum of $p_i$'s has no such constraints. As for the asymmetry - the formula is indeed asymmetric in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the transformation $x_i=1-p_i$. The problem is then equivalent to minimizing
$$
T = \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} x_i x_{i-1}^i x_{i+1}^{n-i} - \left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ i\end{array}\right) x_i
$$
for $x_i\in[0,1]$.
(This target function differs by a constant from the original.)

If $n\le 2$, $T=0$.

If $n=3$, then $T=x_2 x_1^2 x_3 - 3 x_2$. This is minimized when $x_2=1$ and $x_1x_3=0$. Thus,
$$
\mbox{If $n=3$, then $p_2 = 0$ and either $p_1=1$ or $p_3=1$.} 
$$

Suppose $n\ge 4$. Take the derivative with respect to $x_i$:
\begin{eqnarray}
(1) \ \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_1} &=& 2 x_2 x_1 x_3^{n-2} \\
(2) \ \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_2} &=& 3 x_3 x_2^2 x_4^{n-3} + x_1^2 x_3^{n-2} - \left(\begin{array}{c}n \\ 2\end{array}\right)\\
(3)  \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_i} &=&  x_{i-1}^i x_{i+1}^{n-i} + (i+1) x_{i+1} x_i^i x_{i+2}^{n-i-1} + (n-i+1) x_{i-1} x_{i-2}^{i-1} x_i^{n-i} - \left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ i \end{array}\right) \ \ \ \mbox{ for } 2 < i < n-1\\
(4) \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_{n-1}} &=& x_{n-2}^{n-1} x_n + 2 x_{n-2} x_{n-3}^{n-2} x_{n-1} - n\\
(5) \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_n} &=& x_{n-1} x_{n-2}^{n-1}.
\end{eqnarray}

Equation $(3)$ is at most $n+3 - \left(\begin{array}{c} n\\ i\end{array}\right)$ whenever it is valid, i.e., when $n\ge 5$ and $3\le i\le n-2$. But this quantity is *negative*. We conclude that to minimize $T$,
$$
x_i=1 \mbox{ for } 3\le i\le n-2.
$$

Equations $(2)$ and $(4)$ are also negative, showing $x_2=x_{n-1}=1$ as well. Then equation $(5)$ reduces to $1$, so $x_n=0$. Finally, equation $(1)$ reduces to $2x_1$, so $x_1=0$ as well. Hence,
$$
\mbox{If $n\ge 4$, then $p_1=p_n=1$ and $p_i=0$ for other $i$.}
$$

Finally, compute the optimal (original) target function:
\begin{eqnarray}
n=3 &\mapsto& 0 \\
n\ge 4 &\mapsto& n-4.
\end{eqnarray}